# Extremely weird behaviour of auto layout and CALayer

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm using auto layouts and custom layout for my collection view. There were a lot of auto layout warnings initially but I managed to remove all those warnings. Now the views are laid out fine but one of the subviews (a UIButton) of my collection view's cell is behaving weirdly. I have to make this button circular by setting its layer's cornerRadius based on the new frame of the button. Here's the code:

[image]

The frame of this button on storyboard is (8, 6, 52, 52). The debugger output looks something like this:

[image]

You can see that the corner radius of the button's layer is being set to half the height of the button but the resulting view is not what I expect it to be.

[image]

The left grey icon is the view I'm talking about. One can see that it is not circular despite having the corner radius set to half its height.

I have been trying and looking around for a solution for quite a while now. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: where is that code written? In a cell subclass?

Comment: Yes that code is written in cell's class.

Comment: Have you tried implementing the `layoutSubviews` instead? I dont think the `constraint`-method is the correct way to go!?

Comment: I did try doing it in the layoutSubviews method but that changed the entire look of the screen altogether. What else do you suggest?

Comment: Did you call the super method as well `[super layoutSubviews]`?

Comment: Previously I wasn't using the `[super layoutSubviews]`. Calling the super method has solved the issue of laying out the subviews wrongly but the button I'm concerned about is still not round.

Comment: did you call super as the first statement in the method?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88263/discussion-between-adeel-miraj-and-luk2302).

Comment: It looks like the rectangular image you use is about 48x48 points, which is smaller than the 64x64 size of the frame

Comment: That is not the case. The size of the image is 125x125 and the size of the button is 52x52 before laying out all the subviews and 64x64 after all the subviews have been laid out. But still the problem is that it doesn't look like the button has a corner radius of half its height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing some diagnostics (see the [chat session](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88263/discussion-between-adeel-miraj-and-luk2302)), we confirmed that the issue was not in the view hierarchy nor the `cornerRadius` nor anything like that, but a simple border in the underlying image.